# Converting a list of tuples to 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I have a dataset which is a list of tuples, I need to convert this to 3d numpy array. As an example :

```
       data = [(1, 65, -18, -1, -1 ),
       (1, -18,-1, -1,-1),
      (2, 65, -19, -1, -1),
      (2, 65, -18, -1, -1),
       (3, 62, -18, -1, -1)]
```

I would like to create a 3d numpy array like this :

```
     array[[[[65], [-18], [-1], [-1]],
          [[-18], [-1], [-1], [-1]]],
          [[[65], [-19], [-1], [-1]],
          [[65], [-18], [-1], [-1]]],
          [[[62], [-18], [-1], [-1]]]]
```

How can I achieve this with the Numpy library?

I already tried to do in this way :

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    d[item[0]].append((item[1:5]))

# Extract the tuples from the dictionary values using a list 
#comprehension
 values_list = [np.array(v) for v in d.values()]
#print(values_list)
# Convert the list of arrays to a 3D numpy array
my_array = np.array(values_list)
print(my_array)
```

but this gives me a list of 3 arrays, I want just one 3d array, and also I used np.stack but as the length of each array is different it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the 
same shape
```

I am really frustrated, if anyone knows any method please share it with me.

Comment: which is the structure that you intend to use to convert the tuple to the array? this is not clear to me.. Because I cant see a clear order in the arrays that you want to generate

Comment: `(1, -18,-1, -1)` differs in size with other tuples

Comment: Indeed, the number of opening [ and closing ] seems inconsistent, not to mention the values of the tuples don't correspond perfectly to those in the array!

Comment: Yeah, it's really unclear what you're trying to achieve.  What is that first element in each of the lists supposed to be doing.

Comment: The closest to what you seem to want I was able to achieve is: `a= np.array([i for x in data for i in x[1:]]).reshape((5,4,1))`

Comment: sorry guys, I edited my data, so the first element is ID, I would like to create the array-based ID, I already tried to make a dictionary and converted it to 3d numpy array, but it gives me a list of 3 arrays.

Comment: @Swifty thank you for your answer, is there any way I can do this based on the first element which is the ID of my data?

Comment: What does 'based on the 1st element' mean exactly ? I think I'm beginning to see what you want, but you should edit your question to make it clearer! And please fix this number of brackets!

Comment: @Hadis, move the explanation about "ID" logic to the main question

Comment: @Swifty sorry I fixed the brockets, can you help me to build such an array?

Comment: I'm not sure you can create a numpy array that way, because the grouping of tuples by id make it unbalanced dimension-wise; perhaps you'd better use Bruno Magacho's answer, and keep a separate index of id to array-part mapping.

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid 3D numpy array. What you want is not possible with numpy.

Comment: @mozway can you solve my problem with another library in python?

Comment: You can use pure python lists. There is an answer for that below. If you need specialized libraries, you should explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a short way to do it and store in a numpy array is something as

```
import numpy as np

data = [(1, 65, -18, -1, -1 ),
        (1, 65, -18,-1, -1),
        (2, 65, -19, -1, -1),
        (2, 65, -18, -1, -1),
        (3, 62, -18, -1, -1)]

numpy_data = np.array(data)[:,1:].reshape((5,4,1))
numpy_data
```

which outputs

```
array([[[ 65],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[ 65],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[ 65],
        [-19],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[ 65],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[ 62],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]]])
```

from that you can manipulate as you wish

Comment: This is a very clean code, thank you but how can I know which array belongs to which ID?

Comment: May be you can add more details to the question. There is no mention of the ID. since the first value is removed. [1 , 1, 2, 2, 3 ] is it the ID?

Comment: @amranhossen yes they are ids

Comment: so you can acess using `numpy_data[i]` with `i` being the desired index. From this code It is kind of straightforward to manipulate as you want.

Comment: If you create  `id_index = defaultdict(list)` then `for i, line in enumerate(data): id_index[line[0]].append(i)`, you'll have the needed indices to access @BrunoMagacho 's array from each id.

Comment: @BrunoMagacho Thanks for the answer, but I have a large dataset, and it's difficult to use indexing.

Comment: You can also use different types of filters with the ``np.select` function, which might be really usefull on your index issue.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each value, and restucture your list:

```
data = [(1, 65, -18, -1, -1 ),
   (1, -18,-1, -1),
   (2, 65, -19, -1, -1),
   (2, 65, -18, -1, -1),
   (3, 62, -18, -1, -1)]

[[[[val] for val in row[1:]] for row in data]]
```

Output:

```
[[[[65], [-18], [-1], [-1]],
[[-18], [-1], [-1]],
[[65], [-19], [-1], [-1]],
[[65], [-18], [-1], [-1]],
[[62], [-18], [-1], [-1]]]]
```

Comment: This output is correct but its not a numpy array. How can I have a numpy array?

Comment: Wrap your final output in np.array(), Like this : np.array([[[[val] for val in row[1:]] for row in data]])

Answer (score 0):

Apply combination of `np.unique` + `np.split` to get groups of arrays basing on "id" contained in the 1st column of the initial `arr`:

```
arr = np.asarray(data)
groups = np.split(arr[:, 1:], np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_index=True)[1])[1:]
groups = [a.reshape(-1, a.shape[1], 1) for a in groups]
print(groups)
```

---

```
[array([[[ 65],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]]]),
 array([[[ 65],
        [-19],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]],

       [[ 65],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]]]),
 array([[[ 62],
        [-18],
        [ -1],
        [ -1]]])]
```

Comment: This is not strictly a 3D array, but rather a 1D array of arrays, but as I said in my last comment I don't think you can do what the OP wants with numpy anyway :)